# Vector of Pointers to Structure

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Please help where I am getting it wrong below. I want to maintain multiple linked list through vectors.
An entry in a vector should store the pointer of the first node of a doubly linked list.
Below is my code. I have 2 functions first is to insert a node in a given linked list. The header to this linked list will be stored in the vector.

```
typedef long long  ll;
struct block
{
  ll tag;
  bool valid_bit;
  bool dirty_bit;
  block* next;
  block* prev;
};

vector < block* > set;

// Function to Insert new block in the set
void insert(set cashblock, ll tag1=-1,bool d=0) 
{
   temp=cashblock;
   int i=0;
   //check the associativity for the set
   while (temp->prev!=NULL)
   {
......more code here....

}

bool find(set tmp,ll tag1)
{
    while(tmp->prev!=NULL)
    {
...more code here...
}
```

The errors are as follows-

```
43 | void insert(set cashblock,ll tag1=-1,bool d=0)
      |             ^~~
main.cpp:43:16: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘cashblock’
   43 | void insert(set cashblock,ll tag1=-1,bool d=0)
      |            ~   ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                )
main.cpp:43:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘tag1’
   43 | void insert(set cashblock,ll tag1=-1,bool d=0)
      |                              ^~~~
main.cpp:43:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘bool’
   43 | void insert(set cashblock,ll tag1=-1,bool d=0)
      |                                      ^~~~
main.cpp:92:16: error: ‘tmp’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘tp’?
   92 | bool find(set* tmp,ll tag1)
      |                ^~~
      |                tp
```

**One more question:** Also, let me know if I need to access the 0th element from the vector which is a pointer to a linked list. Should it be like set[0]->tag or what is the right way to call.

Comment: `vector < block* > set;` declares `set` as a variable, not as a type alias.

Comment: "_I want to maintain multiple linked list through vectors._" - That would be `std::vector<std::list<T>>`

Comment: and what makes this even worse you are using `using namespace std;` and there is `std::set` template.

Comment: `typedef long long  ll;` -- Don't pick up bad habits from online competition websites.  There is no need for macros like this.  Just use `int64_t`.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
vector < block* > set;
```

This creates a `set` variable, and its type is `vector < block* >`, but you're trying to use `set` like a type:

If you want to create a type alias for `set`, try:

```cpp
using set = std::vector < block* >
```

But I don't know why you don't use the standard `std::set` template

Comment: `std::set` is not a replacement for OPs `std::vector<block*>`, `set` is perhaps just not the best name

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to maintain multiple linked list through vectors."

> No, this is not the way to do it.

---

```
vector < block* > set;
```

This is a variable called set.

```
void insert(set cashblock, ll tag1=-1,bool d=0)
```

This is a function that accepts a **type named set** as param.

To simply fix your errors:

```
#include <vector>


typedef long long  ll;
struct block
{
  ll tag;
  bool valid_bit;
  bool dirty_bit;
  block* next;
  block* prev;
};

using set = std::vector< block* > ; //very bad name, imagine using namespace std, the confusion...
set my_set;

// Function to Insert new block in the set
void insert(set cashblock, ll tag1=-1,bool d=0) { ... }

bool find(set tmp,ll tag1) { ... }
```

---

> I need to access the 0th element from the vector which is a pointer
> to a linked list. Should it be like set[0]->tag

> To access the 1st element from the vector <strike>which is a pointer to a linked list</strike>  which elements are pointers to a struct*, yes you can set[0]->tag